# Retrieve more than 65536 chars from StreamReader

Tags: c#, buffer, streamreader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Socket TCP Send, messages getting “stuck”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501216/c-sharp-socket-tcp-send-messages-getting-stuck)

I'm trying to receive a large message on this TCP client, but I can only get the first 65536 chars.

I saw people saying something about `maxReceivedMessageSize` but it seems it's not for TCP. Also couldn't find how to use it.

I'm using Windows Forms.

This is my code:

Stream Reader declaration:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text));

                writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                network = client.GetStream();
                connected = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Connected successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to server:" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Reading code:

```
   private void ReadDir(object dir)
    {
        if (isConnected())
        {
            JObject o = new JObject();
            string message = null;

            o.Add("comando", (int)Command.READ_DIR);
            o.Add("dir", (string)dir);

            writer.Write(o.ToString());
            writer.Flush();

            Thread.Sleep(500);
            if (client.Available > 0)//returns 65536 or less only
            {
                char[] buffer = new char[client.Available];
                reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                message = new string(buffer);
            }


            if (message != null)
            {

                JArray array = JArray.Parse(message);

                textBox3.Text = (string)dir;
                listView1.Items.Clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i += 5)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem((string)array[i]);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add((string)array[i + 1]);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add((string)array[i + 2]);

                    Debug.WriteLine((string)array[i + 3]);
                    if ((Int64)array[i + 3] > 10 * 1024 * 1024)
                    {
                        lvi.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                    }

                    if ((bool)array[i + 4] == true)
                    {
                        lvi.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    }

                    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I read larger messages at once using the same method I'm using right now?

Comment: It seems to me like you could replace the reading code with `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`, seeing as you already convert the buffer to a string. (Using the default encoding which seems iffy.)

Comment: Also, obligatory style remark: please reduce your code samples to a self-contained test case, don't just copy/paste entire methods from your codebase. 80% of what you posted is completely irrelevant to your problem. Also consider cleaning up indentation.

Comment: @millimoose: I agree, but everytime I do this someone gets angry because they say there is relevant parts missing.

Comment: @millimoose: Could not use .ReadToEnd(), as this is a TCP connection and the StreamWriter on the other end keeps open.

Comment: In that case said people should tell you which parts are missing so you can add them back in. (If not they're being counterproductive.) That said, ideally, it should be possible to copy/paste code samples, add some boilerplate (`using`s, namespaces, a surrounding class), and have them at least compile, if not run and manifest the bug if they depend on some specific input that's not reasonable to include in the post. In your sample, this both isn't possible, and it still certainly is cluttered with stuff that isn't even on the fence when it comes to relevance.

Comment: In that case, just read the data chunk-by-chunk into a `MemoryStream`, then convert that stream's buffer to a string. Stop reading whenever the other end writes some sort of sentinel value that indicates the end of a message. (Honestly, `Stream.Available` just flat out isn't very useful at all. I always default to doing that, it's Sequential IO 101.)

Comment: I'd also consider looking at some library to handle streaming messages over TCP for you instead of handcoding a custom protocol. Something like ZeroMQ or a XMPP implementation.

Comment: That isn't necessarily a duplicate. The data is likely available but just not being read. What does the writing side of this application look like? How do you know when a message ends? It seems like there needs to be a length prefix or a sentinel here.